# How to sum all the numbers in the listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I want to sum all the numbers in the listbox , the numbers are from the database
the date type is money ,and in every time i click the button i want to show the summed of the numbers in the list box .

the code i use :

```
decimal sum = 0;

private void but_TotalSale_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < lst_Price.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToDecimal(lst_Price.Items[i].ToString());
            }

            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
        }
```

And I'm getting this Error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

how to do it ? and how to fix the Error.

the listbox [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIzIN.jpg)

Comment: Well, following the error, what was the input string?  When the error is thrown, what is the value of `lst_Price.Items[i].ToString()`?  (Assuming that's the line that throws the error... is it?)

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the line inside your for-loop and inspect `lst_Price.Items[i]`.

Comment: the times are numbers all of them

Comment: yes it is `lst_Price.Items[i].ToString()`which throws the error.

Comment: there is a pic for the listbox i try to sum .

Comment: If you are sure the items you get are numeric, why do you need to create a string from them to parse them to be numeric again?

Comment: @MaxSaeed: Taking pictures of your user interface isn't the same thing as debugging.  What is the *actual runtime value* of `lst_Price.Items[i].ToString()`?

Comment: sorry it's C# , Visual Studio C# ! , it's the first time i hear about the runtime value . i'm really trying to finish my program cuse tomorrow is my defensand this it the last step

Comment: Change `sum += Convert.ToDecimal(lst_Price.Items[i].ToString());` to `var bob = lst_Price.Items[i].ToString(); sum += Convert.ToDecimal(bob);` (put that over two lines) On the second line, add a breakpoint. Run to the breakpoint. Hover over `bob` and it will tell you the value of `bob`. What is the value of `bob`?

Comment: @MaxSaeed: Then this sounds like a great time to familiarize yourself with the use of the debugger.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243867.aspx  You can use it to step through the code, line by line, as it executes and observe the runtime values and behavior.

Comment: Any luck with this @MaxSaeed ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is you're converting the listitem to a string not using the value inside the list item.

Try this:

```
decimal sum = 0; 
private void but_TotalSale_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
for (int i = 0; i < lst_Price.Items.Count; i++) { 
     sum += Convert.ToDecimal(lst_Price.Items[i].Text);
  } 
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(sum); 
}
```

Comment: ive tried that but didnt work , and i tried to remove the `.text` and `.tostring` but still i have in Error the `.tostring` throws the error anf the text `.text` is not accepted in the code

Answer (score 0):

why you are converting to string in the first place

`lst_Price.Items[i]` is an object and `Convert.ToDecimal()` has an overload which can get an `object`

so can do

```
  for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToDecimal(lst_Price.Items[i]);
            }
```

or in one line with LINQ

```
sum = lst_Price.Items.OfType<object>().Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct. Inside a list Box if there have any text ?